# Problem installing R package with lblas and lapack dependencies

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, r, source-packages

I am trying to install the HMSC R package into RStudio Version 1.2.1335 and  R  version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes" on a Linux Ubuntu 
18.04.2 LTS System

The code to install through R is as follows

```
library(devtools)
install_url('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/BayesLogit/BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz')
install_github("hmsc-r/HMSC", build_opts = c("--no-resave-data", "--no-manual"))
```

When installing BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz I get the following error

```
/home/barefootbushman/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/home/barefootbushman/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'BayesLogit.so' failed
make: *** [BayesLogit.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BayesLogit’
* removing ‘/home/barefootbushman/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BayesLogit’
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpL8qXxH/file18aa17542138/BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have checked for the installation of -lblas and -lapack using

```
sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:3 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                           
Hit:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:5 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease                                    
Get:6 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease [2,456 B]                            
Ign:7 http://dl.bintray.com/basespace/BaseMount-DEB saucy InRelease                                            
Ign:8 http://dl.bintray.com/basespace/BaseSpaceFS-DEB saucy InRelease                          
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:11 http://dl.bintray.com/basespace/BaseMount-DEB saucy Release [1,838 B]                        
Get:12 http://dl.bintray.com/basespace/BaseSpaceFS-DEB saucy Release [1,837 B]                               
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Fetched 6,131 B in 2s (4,067 B/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
```

Followed by

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libblas-dev is already the newest version (3.7.1-4ubuntu1).
liblapack-dev is already the newest version (3.7.1-4ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

However, I still get the same error when attempting to install BayesLogit in R.

Any help on how to overcome this error would be appreciated.
Chris

Comment: The installation appear to be picking up a version of gcc from `/home/barefootbushman/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc` in place of the "system" compiler - is this intended?

Comment: I have miniconda3 installed to run some bioinformatic programs (QIIME2). So unless miniconda3 needs gcc in that directory, no it is not intended.

Comment: In that case I suggest you try setting a more standard `PATH` in your shell before attempting the installation

Comment: using .libPaths ?

Comment: ... I was thinking more like `. /etc/environment` in the terminal before executing `R`

Comment: ok so in a new terminal I ran
`. /etc/environment`
`R`
`library(devtools)`
`install_url('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/BayesLogit/BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz')`

And got the same error. It was still looking in that minconda3 folder

Comment: A similar problem is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58223954/3371413. The solution is to remove conda lines in `.bashrc` that cause the base R install to use the conda install of R for some compilers.

Comment: Thanks @Sav-econ. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the HMISC R package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install r-cran-hmisc
```

The r-cran-hmisc package does not depend on either libblas-dev or liblapack-dev, so you won't get a `cannot find -lblas` or
`cannot find -llapack` error message when trying to install r-cran-hmisc.

The error message that you got when trying to install the HMISC R package is Anaconda's fault for sure, but I don't know where the culprit Anaconda file is located in your system. Usually when a path is borked by Anaconda you can symbolic link it back to the appropriate Ubuntu executable. If Anaconda has messed up too many paths in your system, the only way you're going to get rid of the mess is by completely uninstalling and purging Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks Karel, that is what I ultimately did. Completely re-installed Ubuntu. Have not currently got a conda environment but not looking forward to when I need to used QIIME2 again. Hopefully it doesn't mess everything up again!